# Extract class names from cells in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google spreadsheets & want to copy all class names mentioned in range c3:c51 in to b3. I have tried with filter formula but could not succeed, can you please provide formula for the same, my thanks in advance.
The range C3:C51 contains following data:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="em">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>SSD & ABP Planning 2015-16 </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="beige"  class="body"> 
    <div class="big_wrapper">
        <header id="top_header">
            <h1>Planning 2015-16 (Branch)</h1>
        </header>
        <ul id="menu-bar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sales Tracker</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sales Territory</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Monthly Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deficit detail-CSE wise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Booking detail-CSE wise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Business detail-RBU & CBU</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Business detail-New & Renew</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="line">
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="new_div">
            <section id="main_section" >
                <div class="la1"></div>
            </section>
            <aside id="side_news">
                <h4>Important Points</h4>
                Bloggers rooms is here</aside>
        </div>
        <footer id="the_footer">-For presentation purpose only-</footer>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more clarity please visit following link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HeiMY41qisz3GxbiGbgJcQKH-_c-GeObxQYna8CTd0w/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would want to extract the parts that are highlighted in your example sheet, you could try

```
=query(C3:C52, "where C contains 'class' ")
```

To show all the cells in one cell, try:

```
=join("",C3:C52)
```

If you want to extract the class names only, try

```
=trim(join(" ",arrayformula(iferror(regexreplace(regexextract(regexextract(C3:C52, "(class=(.+?)>.+class=(.+?)>|class=(.+?)>)"), char(34)&"(.+)"&char(34)), char(34)&"(.+)"&char(34)," ")))))
```

Comment: Thanks JPV, but I don't want to copy complete cell content containing class but only want to copy words (only class names) that too in to one single cell, please see if it is possible. Please again see the sheet1

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I would appreciate any answer close to above, like if you can extract words in different cells with or without commas etc, please give any answer close to above

Comment: I entered a new formula (see also edited answer) in cell B3 of sheet 1. See if that works for you ?

Comment: I cannot even explain how grateful I am, you are really super genius, thank you so much it is working fine.

Comment: What is the meaning of char(34)

Comment: char(34) is a double quote